# local:not in a function for variable

Tags: bash

I keep getting "12: local: not in a function" for the code below, which is the first line where "local log" appears. The local variables appear to be set properly in the function. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST="0.0.0.0"
USER="root"
PASS="123"

function login{
 if [ -z "$USER" ]
 then
   echo "pass not set"
 else 
   local log="-u $USER"
   local log+="-p$PASS"
   echo $log
fi 
}

mysql (login) -h $HOST
```

This is on the Ubuntu subsystem on Win 10 in case that matters.

Comment: You are TWICE defining `local log`.

Comment: @Jack Yes, but that's not really an issue. The second one simply (idempotently) makes an already-local variable local again. It doesn't affect the value of the variable at all.

Comment: `shellcheck.net` is very good advice, since there are other issues in the posted code aside from the failure to actually define a function named `login`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function login {
              ^
```

A space is required before the curly brace.

```
mysql $(login) -h $HOST
      ^
```

You're also missing a dollar sign here.

Comment: Perhaps try switching over to different function syntax:  `login() {` instead of `function login {` I'm not able to replicate the issues myself though (using ubuntu server 14.04.5)

Comment: I think it was the subsystem. When I switched to Ubuntu, it worked. Thanks everyone for your help.